# Sign in from Google Drive Android app

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-chrome-app, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to use the Google client API and the Google Drive API to log in and display information contained in DICOM (*.dcm) files stored on Google Drive via the 'Open With' functionality.

The code:

```js
gapi.load('client:auth2', onApiLoad);

function onApiLoad() {
    gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': apiKey,
        'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest'],
        'clientId': clientId,
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
    }).then( function () {
        console.log('init success');
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('init fail', error);
    });
}
```

The init using `gapi.client.init` works fine from a desktop browser but fails from the drive mobile app (v2.7.252.04.33 from 28 Jun 2017, Android 6.0) complaining that `sessionStorage is not available in the current the environment` (error: `idpiframe_initialization_failed`).

I wrote an issue on the Google Client GitHub (https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/324) which answer suggests to ask drive people about what authorization to use.

So I ask here, is what I am trying to do possible from the Google Drive app and what authorization should I use?

For reference, here is the Chrome app manifest:

```json
{
  "name": "dwvgapi",
  "short_name": "dwvgapi",
  "description": "Google API test for dwv. Used for testing purposes only.",
  "version": "0.1.0.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "urls": [
      "https://ivmartel.github.io/dwvgapi/demo/"
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "https://ivmartel.github.io/dwvgapi/demo/index.html"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "50": "resources/icons/dwvgapi-50.png",
    "128": "resources/icons/dwvgapi-128.png"
  },
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "container": "GOOGLE_DRIVE",
  "api_console_project_id": "575535891659",
  "gdrive_mime_types": {
    "http://drive.google.com/intents/opendrivedoc": [
      {
        "type": ["application/dicom", "application/vnd.google.drive.ext-type.dcm"],
        "href": "https://ivmartel.github.io/dwvgapi/demo/index.html",
        "title": "Open",
        "disposition": "window"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note: the repo is open source: https://github.com/ivmartel/dwvgapi (init code in https://github.com/ivmartel/dwvgapi/blob/master/src/google.js) and the Chrome app has the same name (dwvgapi).

Note 2: the code is similar to the drive quickstart example (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js#step_2_set_up_the_sample)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Edited to add code and manifest. Hope it is better.

Comment: Are you sure this is a Chrome extension? This appears to be a Chrome App, not a Chrome extension. The `"app"` key is not valid in [Chrome extension *manifest.json* files](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest). The `"app"` key is, however, [valid in Chrome **apps**](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest). If it's an app, please edit the tags in the question to reflect that.

Comment: It's an app, my mistake.